# Graity Forms is there a way for a product to have an offline payment

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a gravity form where there is a product. I have one type of payment method which is PayPal and would like to have a second one where the user either pays instore or is sent an invoice. I have a condition that hides the PayPal credit card but if it's not filled in then the form does not submit.

Answer (score 0):

We do this on our website. We use Stripe but the conditional only shows the CC field if "Pay by CC" is checked--so you can submit the form as long as "Pay by pledge" is checked. (When pledging, a hidden discount field is enabled which discounts the total by 100%.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set your PayPal feed to only run when the payment method is selected as PayPal.
[image]

See documentation: https://docs.gravityforms.com/setting-up-conditional-payments/